# Long Array VBA Issue

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to enter a long-array Formula into VBA that is >255 characters. I have followed past suggestions to dim both halves of the formula and merge them later. I am still having errors getting the array to function properly and was hoping someone could help review the code.

Here's the original code that exceeds the character limit I'm trying to get working:

```
Sub TestMacro()

Range("AZ7").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = _
    "=SUM(IF(CONCATENATE(R3C3,[@Route],[@[Assumed Coating Type]],[@Diameter],[@[Year Installed (Coating)]])=CONCATENATE(HCA!R26C[86]:R13642C[86],HCA!R26C[-48]:R13642C[-48],HCA!R26C[87]:R13642C[87],HCA!R26C[-19]:R13642C[-19],HCA!R26C[88]:R13642C[88]),HCA!R26C[-36]:R13642C[-36]))"
```

End Sub

Here is my latest attempt to split the code in half following past advice: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/853889-long-array-visual-basic-applications-issue.html

http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/01/10/entering-long-array-formulas-in-vba/

```
Sub LongArrayFormula()
 Dim theFormulaPart1 As String
 Dim theFormulaPart2 As String
 theFormulaPart1 = "=SUM(IF(CONCATENATE(R3C3,[@Route],[@[Assumed Coating Type]],[@Diameter],[@[Year Installed (Coating)]])""X_X_X)"")"

 theFormulaPart2 = "=CONCATENATE(HCA!R26C[86]:R13642C[86],HCA!R26C[-48]:R13642C[-48],HCA!R26C[87]:R13642C[87],HCA!R26C[-19]:R13642C[-19],HCA!R26C[88]:R13642C[88]),HCA!R26C[-36]:R13642C[-36]))"

 With ActiveSheet.Range("AZ7")
     .FormulaArray = theFormulaPart1
    .Replace """X_X_X)"")", theFormulaPart2

End With
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you really want to have an equals at the start of `theFormulaPart2`? Seems like it would error having 2 equals signs in the concatenated formula...

Comment: Hi @Wolfie, no, but I have tried it both ways and still end up with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep your truncated formula *syntactically* correct. Try it like this:

```
theFormulaPart1 = "=SUM(IF(CONCATENATE(R3C3,[@Route],[@[Assumed Coating Type]],
[@Diameter],[@[Year Installed (Coating)]])=X_X_X,HCA!R26C[-36]:R13642C[-36]))"
'                                          ^^^^^
theFormulaPart2 = "CONCATENATE(HCA!R26C[86]:R13642C[86],HCA!R26C[-48]:R13642C[-48],HCA!R26C[87]:R13642C[87],HCA!R26C[-19]:R13642C[-19],HCA!R26C[88]:R13642C[88])"

With ActiveSheet.Range("AZ7")
  .FormulaArray = theFormulaPart1
  .Replace "X_X_X", theFormulaPart2
End With
```

Here I inserted `X_X_X` (could be anything else) in the place of some "closed expression" in the formula. That keeps the truncated formula correct from a syntax point of view, so the statement `.FormulaArray = theFormulaPart1` can accept it. Replacement can then proceed in the second step.

Comment: Hi ASH, thanks for the help! The script is running into a small problem where the script is pasting '=SUM(IF(CONCATENATE($C$3,[@Route],[@[Assumed Coating Type]],[@Diameter],[@[Year Installed (Coating)]])="X_X_X",HCA!P$26:P$13642))' in AZ7. It doesn't seem to be replacing the "X_X_X". Any ideas?

Comment: I believe there is a problem with the .Replace function. I've tried a few variations and have come to no success in trying to have the X_X_X replaced.

Comment: @WilliamC. the replaced form wont appear in the formula bar until you deselect then select the cell (I have no clue why). Besides, the resulting formula must also be correct, otherwise it wont succeed. It's very hard to debug this formula so I assumed it was correct and tested my code with smaller, "correct" formulas.

Comment: @WilliamC. However I am pretty sure about the essence of the issue, you can't just truncate any part of the formula, you should keep it correct from a syntax point of view or Excel wont accept it.

Comment: Hi ASH, thanks for the advice. Yes, the formula is accurate if entered normally. I'll tweak some things in the morning and see if I can get it to work. In the meantime, I'll mark this as answered since you've provided a lot of useful information. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this(
please don't run it from the VBE, try to run it from sheets environment. Go to Developer-Macros-Your Macro -Run or Run it from a button or shortcut and it will work without problem):

```
Range("AZ7").Select
Selection.Formula = _
    "=SUM(IF(CONCATENATE(R3C3,[@Route],[@[Assumed Coating Type]],[@Diameter],[@[Year Installed (Coating)]])=CONCATENATE(HCA!R26C[86]:R13642C[86],HCA!R26C[-48]:R13642C[-48],HCA!R26C[87]:R13642C[87],HCA!R26C[-19]:R13642C[-19],HCA!R26C[88]:R13642C[88]),HCA!R26C[-36]:R13642C[-36]))"

SendKeys "{F2}"
SendKeys "^+{ENTER}"
```